# subtracting values in two columns and obtaining a new column using pig

Tags: apache-pig

i have a bunch of rows filtered according to my criterion. now i need the subtracted values of two columns and i need to sort them. these are the commands i used till now.

```
data = LOAD '/user/imohit01017881/jk/a2dbe50d-c6e5-42e2-8fd0-5386720ce07b_Data.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS  (Country:chararray, CountryCode:chararray, Series:chararray, SeriesCode:chararray,  yr2000: float, yr2001:float, yr2002 :float, yr2003 :float,  yr2004 :float, yr2005:float,  yr2006:float, yr2007:float, yr2008 :float,  yr2009 :float, yr2010:float, yr2011: float, yr2012 :float, yr2013 : float, yr2014 : float, yr2015:float);
```

**Filter rows containing req data:**

```
ggdif = FILTER  data by Series == 'Improved sanitation facilities (% of population with access)' 
dump data
```

Below line is giving me error:

```
sub_data = FOREACH ggdif GENERATE SUBTRACT(yr2015, yr2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/SUBTRACT.html): SUBTRACT takes two bags as arguments and returns a new bag composed of tuples of first bag not in the second bag.
If null, bag arguments are replaced by empty bags

```
sub_data = FOREACH ggdif GENERATE (yr2015 - yr2000);
```